# Why aren't namespace autoload classes loading in phpunit tests?

Tags: namespaces, phpunit, php, autoload

To compliment an existing smorgasbord of arrangements between phpunit,autoload and namespace is this:

I have created a simple test project that runs PhpUnit tests and uses namespace autoloading. I register the autoloading in the bootstrap file like so:

```
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . "/path/to/classes/folder");
spl_autoload_register();
```

and inside a unit test I load and test my class like so:

```
$obj = new \some\space\someClass(); // which is in the classes/some/space folder
$this->assertTrue($obj->foo()=='bar');
```

And I get an error

> Fatal error: Class '\some\space\someClass' not found in testSomeClass.php...

Comment: And `someClass` is defined in `classes/some/space/someClass.php` with case matching *exactly?*

Comment: yes, I actually used my ide's (phpstorm) autocomplete for the most part.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While this is not phpunit specific you need to change:

```
spl_autoload_register();
```

to

```
spl_autoload_register('spl_autoload');
```

Any other component that registers an autoloader unregisters the default `__autoload()`.

> If your code has an existing __autoload function then this function must be explicitly registered on the __autoload stack. This is because spl_autoload_register() will effectively replace the engine cache for the __autoload function by either spl_autoload() or spl_autoload_call().

So this is how [**`spl-autoload`**](http://php.net/spl-autoload) works together with anything else that uses autoloading.

Comment: While your answer does solve the problem, I'm not very clear as to why that is, considering that it worked fine with the first call (without 'spl_autoload' string as a parameter), and the only place it ceased is when I was using it inside phpunit. Thanks

Comment: According to the docs for [`spl_autoload_register()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php) "if no parameter is provided, then the default implementation of `spl_autoload()` will be registered." No parameter should be equivalent to passing `'spl_autoload'` and the above change should have no effect! Awesome. :)

Answer (score 4):

Make sure your path to classes folder is made relative to script which is run for tests execution. If the script is in subfolder of your projects (for example `tests/`) then your path should be `../path/to/classes/folder`

That's what I have in my `tests/bootstrap.php`

```
set_include_path(dirname(__FILE__).'/../classes'.PATH_SEPARATOR.get_include_path());

spl_autoload_extensions('.php');
spl_autoload_register('spl_autoload');
```

Comment: right, I've tried using absolute paths, with the same results

Comment: I've tried various combinations of relative paths as well, still with no luck

Comment: does your autoload work when runnng the application normally?

Comment: Mchl, have you ever had phpunit working with this sort of class autoloading? I'm asking because an affirmative to this would mean that this is a fault of configuration on my machine, rather than a quirk of phpunit, or other.

Comment: Yeah... I'll paste a few lines from my bootstrap for your reference.

Comment: How odd - I've changed spl_autoload_register() to spl_autoload_register('spl_autoload') and now it's working

Comment: Huh... TBH I forgot why I did it this way in the first place. Mybe I had the same problem too...

Comment: This was really helpful. I also didn't think of a test bootstrap file. Do you include this file in the setUp() method of all your tests?

Comment: You provide the name of a bootstrap file from command line when running phpunit, or within your xml config file. See http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/textui.html